# loading view via java-script

Tags: javascript, html

i have a main html page (index.html)

```
<body>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                function active(el) {
                    var sections = document.querySelectorAll('.sidebar>li');
                    for (i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
                        sections[i].classList.remove('current');
                    }
                    el.classList.add('current');
                }
            </script>
            <h1 onclick="active(this); load('content','pages/home.html')" class="sidebar-title">GOSSAMER LAN</h1>
            <ul class="sidebar">
                <li onclick="active(this); load('content','pages/network.html')">
                    <h2>Network settings</h2>
                    <small>Edit configuration</small>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
        <section id="content"></section>
    </section>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>


</body>
```

and network setting view (network.html) that has a button

```
 <div class="save-button" onclick="validation();">Save changes</div>
```

what i want to do is on clicking the button to return to view (home.html)

```
function validation() {
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text],input[type=password]');
    var input = [];
    for (p = 0; p < inputs.length; p++) {
        input.push(inputs[p].value);

        if (!inputs[p].parentNode.classList.contains("deactive")) {
            inputs[p].value == "" ? inputs[p].classList.add("error") : inputs[p].classList.remove("error")
        }
    }
    if (input.indexOf("") == -1) {
        sendData();
        load("content","pages/home.html");

    }
```

via my java script code

```
function load(page,src) {
    console.log( document.getElementById(page));
    document.getElementById(page).innerHTML='<object type="text/html" id="dynamic-'+page+'" data="'+src+'" style="width:100%; height: 100%;" ></object>';

}
load("content","pages/home.html");
```

i have put most of my code to make it kind of detailed as to what i hope to achieve i am getting Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null when executing the onclick function (validation)

please any help ?
thank you

Comment: What does the console output here `console.log( document.getElementById(page));`?

Comment: @MoaazBhnas null , because it doesn't recognize the section element in my index.html with id="content"

Comment: @MoaazBhnas but it is not working and that's what i need help with, to make it work

Comment: Very strange! I'm really sorry, I can't find the reason for it not to work ..